# How to update a matplotlib figure from loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

the title says it.

I want to draw the evolution of a point cloud using matplotlib. Therefore I want to redraw the figure in the same window in every loop iteration without blocking the application.

Edit 1: pseudo snippet of my code

```
x,y = init_points()  // x,y are 2D coordinates

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
while transformation:
  x, y= transform(x,y)
  plt.plot(x, y)
  plt.draw()
```

Basically I managed to draw the points. But the new points are added to the old figure. I want to completely redraw the figure.

I think I need something similar to Matlab's hold on/ hold off

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code this yourself? If so, can you provide that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you:

```
plt.clf()
```

This clears the figure.